# Druid - Streaming Data Ingestion - Continuous Aggregations

Tags: stream, druid

I am looking at using Druid for aggregations. My use case is that I want to stream data into Druid (which is for same day with segmentGranularity set to DAY) and during ingestion time i want to aggregate data.

My question is, when we send the first stream of data, the data gets rolled up and aggregations are calculated and written to Druid. Now, when I send another stream of data to Druid (which relates to the data that already rolled up) how does druid handle it.

Does druid update the aggregated data or it will just append this data to existing aggregated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for commenting. I am able to get druid working with streaming ingestion and also aggregations.

I found that when data is streamed again, the data aggregation is getting updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Druid works on 2 types of ingestion - Streaming Ingestion and Batch File ingestion. For streaming ingestion its done through Tranquality server or Firehose connected to kafka (push vs pull). -

> For streaming data the rollup aggregation are appended to the
>   previous data.

For batch ingestion - Druid re-ingests entire data for the given timeframe or segment.

For your use case (daily), If you don't have duplicate data problem (i,e same data stream may come again) you can do streaming ingestion, otherwise preferable is Batch ingestion done at specified time interval eg. hourly.